# How to get data from QTableView by pressing Enter Key in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm making an app with PyQt5 and facing some troubles. I want to select data from QTableView by pressing Enter key and display it in QLineEdit. I've done these things with doubleClicked signals but I still want to display data to QLineEdit by both 2 ways and then close QTableView dialog right after pressing Enter key or double clicking.
Here is my code:

```
import sys 
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.mainwindow = uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)

        self.mainwindow.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.table)

    def table(self):
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        data = [
            [2, 3, 5], 
            [23, 4, 5],
            [2, 6, 7],
            [0, 3, 5]
        ]

        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.table.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.table.show()

    def on_click(self, signal):
        row = signal.row()  # RETRIEVES ROW OF CELL THAT WAS DOUBLE CLICKED
        column = signal.column()  # RETRIEVES COLUMN OF CELL THAT WAS DOUBLE CLICKED
        cell_dict = self.model.itemData(signal)  # RETURNS DICT VALUE OF SIGNAL
        cell_value = cell_dict.get(0)  # RETRIEVE VALUE FROM DICT

        index = signal.sibling(row, 0)
        index_dict = self.model.itemData(index)
        index_value = index_dict.get(0)
        print(
            'Row {}, Column {} clicked - value: {}\n'.format(row, column, cell_value))

        self.mainwindow.lineEdit.setText('%s' %cell_value)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):

        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):

        return len(self._data[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Application()
    window.show()
    application.exec_()
```

And my Gui:

[image]

Lets me explain a little bit: when click on pushbutton, it shows up a data table, and then I want to select data in the table by pressing enter key, after that it will display data into QlineEdit and close the table

Comment: In order to help you with your issue you need to supply the UI that you are using otherwise your MRE is not an MRE because it will not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is to detect the keypress, for example using an eventFilter, and then obtain the QModelIndex of the selected element:

```py
class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test.ui", self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.table)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table.doubleClicked.connect(self.write_text)
        self.table.installEventFilter(self)

    def table(self):
        data = [[2, 3, 5], [23, 4, 5], [2, 6, 7], [0, 3, 5]]
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.table.show()

    def write_text(self, index):
        row, column, cell_value = index.row(), index.column(), index.data()
        print("Row {}, Column {} clicked - value: {}".format(row, column, cell_value))
        self.lineEdit.setText("%s" % cell_value)
        self.table.close()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.table and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
                indexes = self.table.selectedIndexes()
                if indexes:
                    self.write_text(indexes[0])
        return super(Application, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Comment: But after that, I want to close the table data dialog, only remaining mainwindow. How can I do that? Can you show me how to implement it?

Comment: can I ask you a question? @eyllanesc